# If $T\alpha = c\alpha$ and $f$ is any polynomial, then $f(T)\alpha = f(c)\alpha$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials, linear-transformations

I'm reading the great [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/teachers/anjp/textbook.pdf) and I want to make sure I'm proving this lemma in the correct way (page 186):

> ***Lemma.*** *Suppose that $T\alpha = c\alpha$. If $f$ is any polynomial, then $f(T)\alpha = f(c)\alpha$.*
>
> *Proof.* Exercise.

### My proof:

If $f(x)=a_nX^n+\dots+a_1X+a_0$, then $f(T)=a_nT^n+\dots+a_1T+a_0I$.

Therefore, when we apply $f(T)$ to $\alpha$, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
f(T)\alpha&=a_nT^n\alpha+\dots+a_1T\alpha+a_0I\alpha\\&=a_n(c^n\alpha)+\dots+(a_1c\alpha)+a_0\alpha\\&=(a_nc^n+\dots+a_1c+a_0)\alpha\\&= f(c)\alpha.\end{align}$$

---

Am I right? Is my definition $f(T)=a_nT^n+\dots+a_1T+a_0I$ right? I don't remember where Hoffman and Kunze define a polynomial applied to a linear transformation.

Comment: Yes, your proof and definition are both perfectly fine.

Comment: @EuYu thank you for your comment. Do you know where Hoffman and Kunze define $f(T)$? I couldn't find it.

Comment: It's a little hard to find, but it's on page 121, where they define the evaluation map on an algebra.

Comment: @EuYu : I would add one other thing to the proof. See my answer below.

Comment: @EuYu Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T\alpha = c\alpha,$ where $T$ is a linear transformation and $c$ is a scalar, then why is $T^n\alpha = c^n \alpha\text{?}$

That has a short proof by induction on $n.$ I would include that.